# ng grid passing variables in cellTemplate

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, ng-grid

I have an ng-grid that is connected to a SharePoint list. The SharePoint list is returning an ID number instead of the user name when I am trying to populate a  field with a user name.

I have a function that is converting the ID to a user name.

```
$scope.getUserName = function (user) {
    var userId = user;
    $Service.getUserById($scope, userId).done(function (data) {
        $scope.userName = data.d.Title;
    })
}
```

When I am trying to call the function in a "cellTemplate", I can't send the ID variable to the function.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    loading: true,
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFullRowSelection: true,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
    showGroupPanel: true,
    columnDefs: [
        { name: "Admin", field: "AdministratorId" },
        { name: "User", field: "ApprovedById" },
        { name: "SuperUser", cellTemplate: '<div>{{grid.appScope.getUserName(<pass the id variable here>)}}{{grid.appScope.userName}}</div>' }
    ],
    data: 'gridData'
};
```

How do I get the userID from 'gridData' and send it to my function?

Update: The REST call I am using.

```
function getListItem(listName) {

var deferred = $.Deferred();
// query the list in the host web
var url = SPAppWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)" +
"/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?" +
"@target='" + SPHostUrl + "'";

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }, // return data format
    success: onGetEntriesSuccess,
    error: onoDataCallFailure
});
function onGetEntriesSuccess(data) {
    deferred.resolve(data.d);
}
function onoDataCallFailure(data, errorcode, errorMessage) {
    deferred.reject("Error: " + errorMessage);
}
return deferred;}
```

Comment: Why not just get the username right away instead of the ID and add it to your scope?

Comment: Could you give me a example? Rest call to SharePoint returns the userID instead of the name.

Comment: What REST call are you doing?

Comment: I updated my question with my REST call

Comment: Use the `$expand` OData property by adding it to your first querystring.`?$select=Author&$expand=Author`. Read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx).

Comment: I do not understand, i am getting the list with REST. Two columns in the list are "People and Groups" columns, my goal is to populate my ng-grid with these user names in the field.

Comment: There is a difference between getting the *list* or the *list items*. Are the two columns lookup columns? In that case, you should be able to expand those. `var url = SPAppWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)" + "/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=People/Title&$expand=People/Title" + "&@target='" + SPHostUrl + "'";`

Comment: Thank you Daniel B. That explained it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code: 
cellTemplate:

```
'<div>{{grid.appScope.getUserName(**<pass the id variable here>**)}}{{grid.appScope.userName}}</div>'
```

Pass id like this : row.entity.Id  // this id is available in your raw data.

and now code is:

```
cellTemplate: '<div>{{grid.appScope.getUserName(row.entity.Id)}}{{grid.appScope.userName}}</div>'
```